# angular - make it to call api that accept json format

Tags: json, angularjs

I am very new to angularjs.

I am trying to make the http call and posting object to the api which only accept json.

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
var app = angular.module('ngShow', ['ngRoute','ngResource']);

app.
config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html' });
  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});

}]);

app.
config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
        delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000';
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/javascript';
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
        $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
}]);
```

but seems doesn't work from the request headers.

```
Request Headers 15:31:10.000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0
Pragma: no-cache
Origin: http://localhost:63342
Host:   localhost:8080
DNT:    1
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control:  no-cache
Access-Control-Request-Method:  POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-max-age
Accept-Language:    en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
```

### UPDATE #001

Added my loginService.js - it is calling the api ok but just not the json.

```
app.factory('loginService', function($http){
    return{
        login:function(user){
            console.log("enter login service");

            var $promise=$http.post('http://localhost:8080/api/login',user); //send data to the api

            $promise.then(function(msg){
                if(msg.data=='succes') console.log('succes login');
                else console.log('error login');

            });

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share the code with the API call?

Comment: Two things: (1) I don't understand what you mean by "it is calling the api ok but just not the json", and (2) Can I assume that the `user` param in your `login()` method is an, which you're going to send as your as your JSON payload?

Comment: One more question: Is this a Cross-Origin request? I did not take that into consideration in my answer.

Comment: ok, i didn't know such thing as payload before, looking into it. yes it is cross-origin

Comment: Ok, just searched that X-XSS-Protection[29] Cross-site scripting (XSS) filter X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
so can't do cross origin request on localhost with different ports?
i got lots to learn, I am java backend developer, just learning the frontend.

Comment: Cross-origin request are handled very differently (using JSONP). It will also require changes to your server-side code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `user` param in the `login()` method of your `loginService` factory is the object you want to send as your JSON payload, you can try the following:

```
    var payload = JSON.stringify(user);

    var promise = $http({
        url: '/api/login',
        method: 'POST',
        data: payload,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    });

    promise.then(function(...) {
       ...
    });
```

**UPDATE:**

I would also consolidate the two `.config()` calls in your code.

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/login', {templateUrl: 'partials/login.html' });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/login'});

    delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json, text/javascript';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
    $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
}]);
```

You're already setting the `Content-Type` header globally (i.e. for all requests) using `$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Content-Type']`, so the `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}` in my code above is redundant.

Comment: Ok will try that, plus how can I make it globally setting for all the http method instead of individually set the headers?

Comment: Regarding the headers, you're already doing it. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I've got following concerns here:

1. You use 2 `config` sections for one module. Not sure if this approach is expected.
2. Accordingly [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#setting-http-headers), such params are set in `run` section

Comment: While I agree Jaxox should consolidate both `config` sections into a single one, setting default headers for the `$http` service can either be done in `.run()` using `$http.defaults.headers` or in `.config()` using `$httpProvider.defaults.headers`.